# Validate if URL exist in List using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I Have a object List and I need to validate to check if a given url exist in the list. Think LINQ will be a good approach, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

```
var url1 = new WhiteListItem() {Url = "*.aaaaa.com/*"};
var url2 = new WhiteListItem() { Url = "www.bbbbb.com/*" };
var url3 = new WhiteListItem() { Url = "www.ccccc.com" };
var url4 = new WhiteListItem() { Url = "www.ddddd.com/ddddddd" };

var validUrls = new List<WhiteListItem> {url1, url2, url3, url4};
```

*Just to clarify, I'm trying to get the following results for given url:*

1. *True* - www.aaaaa.com/something?aaa=something/something
2. *True* - mobi.aaaaa.com/Something
3. **False** - aaaaa.com **(Because no sub-domain present)**
4. *True* - www.bbbbb.com/something/something
5. *True* - www.bbbbb.com
6. *False* - mobi.bbbbb.com **(Because only www sub-domain allowed)**

I Think you get the picture. Please help or just point me in a correct direction. Code examples will be highly appreciated.

---

@stovroz, thanx for coming back to me. I thought I should do something like that, here is my function: Please let me know if you see any loopholes. Not sure if the use of a stringbuilder was an overkill?

And Then 1 last question how can I say that "/" can be present at the end but not permitted to pass.

```
private static Regex CreateRegularExpression(string urlString)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(urlString.Trim());

    sb.Replace(".", @"\.");
    if (sb.ToString().EndsWith(@"/"))
    {
        sb.Append("?");
    }

    if (sb.ToString().EndsWith(@"/*"))
    {
        sb.Insert(sb.Length - 1, '.');
    }

    if (sb.ToString().IndexOf("https://", StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
    {
        sb.Replace("https://", @"\bhttps://");
    }
    else if (sb.ToString().IndexOf("http://", StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
    {
        sb.Replace("http://", @"\bhttp://");
    }
    else
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder(Config.AllowedProtocolRegExp + sb.ToString());
    }

    sb.Replace(@"://*\.", @"://[\x2DA-Za-z0-9]*\.");

    return new Regex(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better if you could express your whitelist rules as regular expressions, either as a single composite regular expression, or as a list of separate expressions and checking if any match, something like:

```
var whitelist = new [] {@".*\.aaaaa\.com/*.", @"www.bbbbb.com/.*"};
var list = new [] { "mobi.aaaaa.com/Something", "mobi.bbbbb.com/" };
var matches = list.Where(x => whitelist.Any(y => Regex.IsMatch(x, y)));
```

Update:

As you've got a large number of patters to match on which are already in wildcard syntax, you can convert those to Regex syntax first by using the following function:

```
public string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{
  return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).
  Replace("\\*", ".*").
  Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
}
```

(from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11556/Converting-Wildcards-to-Regexes)

so:

```
var wildcardWhitelist = new [] { "*.aaaaa.com/*", "www.bbbbb.com/*" };
var regexWhitelist = wildcardWhitelist.Select(x => WildcardToRegex(x));
var list = new [] { "mobi.aaaaa.com/Something", "mobi.bbbbb.com/" };
var matches = list.Where(x => regexWhitelist.Any(y => Regex.IsMatch(x, y)));
```

Comment: Hi Guys, thanx for joining. First off I'm new to C#. The example List that I gave you was just to try to explain the format that the white list url's come in. It is actually a huge list (json) that I import into this format.

I thought LINQ was my problem understanding but now there is Regular Expressions as well, :) he he.

Maybe my Original question was misleading. The List of "WhiteListItems" are all the valid url's "Patterns". I get passed a unknown url that I must check to see if it is in the WhiteListItems.

Comment: The approach I thought of taking was: If I get passed a url: `http://www.domain.com/subdir/subdir/file.html` I would like to check the whitelist if I can find anything *LIKE* domain.com. if I found anything, then I will start checking if the sub domain is valid and if any paths are allowed. _Hope this makes more sence_ @stovroz @Wahid Bitar

Comment: Hi @DickSwart. In that case you can convert your pattens to Regex syntax first. Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var urls = new List<WhiteListItem>
{
    new WhiteListItem() {Url = "*.aaaaa.com/*"},
    new WhiteListItem() { Url = "www.bbbbb.com/*" },
    new WhiteListItem() { Url = "www.ccccc.com" },
    new WhiteListItem() { Url = "www.ddddd.com/ddddddd" };
};
var validatedUrls = urls.Select(u => new 
{
    // here you can use Regular Expression pattern to validate your Urls 
    //or you can use your custom method
    IsPassed = Regex.IsMatch("",u.Url),
    Url = u.Url,
}).ToList();

var goodUrls = validatedUrls.Where(u=> u.IsPassed).Select(u=>u.Url);
var badUrls = validatedUrls.Where(u=> !u.IsPassed).Select(u=>u.Url);
```

Comment: Isn't this getting the whitelist and input list a bit muddled up?

Comment: Sorry you mean i missed the `!u.IsPassed` part right ? 
Anyway I updated my answer